# How do I loop through a list?

Tags: python, loops, for-loop

I'm trying to loop over a list, but unless I specify what section of the list to loop through, it doesn't work (I want it to loop over the WHOLE list not just one part e.g list1[1] etc.

```
input1 = input("Corrupted: ")
words = input1.split()
a = 0
final1 = ""
for i in words[a]:
  a = a + 1
  if i in "ATGC":
    final1 = final1 + i
print(final1)
```

When I run that, it prints out nothing. However, if I change the 'a' to a hard coded 0 it prints out the correct input for words[0] only. I don't understand since I assigned a to 0, and incremented it by 1 each time. It still didn't print anything!

Comment: What does `words` look like? And what is your output here and your expected one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can iterate directly over a list:

```
for i in words:
    if i in "ATGC":
        final1 = final1 + i
print(final1)
```

There are simpler ways to write this, like a list comprehension:

```
final1 = [i for i in words if i in "ATGC"]
```

Or for better performance using a frozen set, if you're dealing with single letters at a time in your input:

```
acids = frozenset(('A', 'T', 'G', 'C'))
final1 = [i for i in words if i in acids]
```

Either of those will return a list of strings - to get a single string back, use `join`:

```
print (''.join(final1))
```

Comment: If one of the answers solved your problem, you may wish to accept an answer as explained here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235

Answer (score 0):

`for i in words[a]` does not do what you think it does. With `a = 0`, `words[a]` will always be length 1, with the zeroth element.  So, your loop will only ever run once.

Iterate over the list directly instead:

```
for i in words:
    if i in "ATGC":
        final1 = final1 + i
```

Comment: As a small quibble - `words[a]` will be a string, so it could be of any possible length.  Suppose the input is 'GATTACAGATTACA ATTACA'.  Then `words[0]` is 'GATTACAGATTACA', and `for i in words[a]` will inspect that letter by letter.  We agree on the solution, although I didn't take the possibility of multiple-letter substrings into account either until I saw that "will always be length 1" statement.  The OP's desired behavior is guesswork, so I'm not sure how much that matters.